# Creating 16 bit greyscale PNGs in Node.js out of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, png

I'm generating PNGs in Node.js using two dimensional arrays. I was using [Jimp](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jimp) but it only generates images with an 8 bit depth. This causes visible bands of colour ([see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRIkZ.png)). Is there a node.js library for generating images like this with a higher bit depth?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try lwip module?

```
npm install lwip
```

lwip much faster than Jimp (see: [images-manipulation-performance](https://www.npmjs.com/package/images-manipulation-performance))

Followed example make 1.png file in RGBa collor mode (32-bit depth) and much less file size.

```
var lwip = require('lwip');

lwip.create(833, 716, {r: 49, g: 49, b: 49, a: 100}, function(err, image){
  // check err
  image.writeFile('1.png', 'png', function(err){
      // check err...
      // done. check 1.png file
    })
});
```

Comment: When I said 8 bit depth I meant that it only has 8 bits per channel. I need it to have enough depth to cover more than 256 grey scale levels (look at the image it has visible bands).